# Change chart values on the graphic axes. Language R

Tags: r, lattice, graphic

I need to change chart values on the vertical y axes. I have such a data.
[image]

I need that on the y axes will be values like GNP has, from 500 to 3000, not from 1 to 20.
Here is my code for drawing graphic.

```
      library(lattice)
      data(Investment, package="sandwich")
      Investment <- as.data.frame(Investment)
      stripplot(Investment$GNP~Investment$Investment|"Graphic", 
      right = F, xlab="Investment", ylab="GNP")
```

[image]

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an `xyplot` instead:

```
library(lattice)
data(Investment, package = "sandwich")
Investment <- as.data.frame(Investment)

xyplot(
  x = GNP ~ Investment | "Graphic",
  data = Investment,
  right = F,
  xlab = "Investment",
  ylab = "GNP"
)
```

Comment: Thank's, but can I do this with stripplot graphic?

Comment: You shouldn't, because stripplot is a univariate scatterplot. This means its purpose is to plot only one quantitative variable, perhaps separated by several factors. That is why your y-axis data is treated as factors.

Comment: Ok, tell me please what other graphic besides of `xyplot` I can use for two variables? I need to use six different graphics to analyse the data. Barchart, dotplot, bwplot also doesn't work correctly.

Comment: You can use `plot` from base `graphics` or `ggplot` from `ggplot2`. Those are my suggestions. The `lattice` package is a little bit more cumbersome I guess.

Comment: I need use graphics only from lattice package. So no other options besides of `xyplot`?

Comment: To get some ideas, take a look [here](https://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/trellis.html). On that page, you see 8 different types of `lattice` plots.